# Getting all variables declared in a scope - C++

Tags: c++, variables

Is it possible to make a struct or class in C++ to get a list of the defined variables declared within a scope in C++. I don't want to hard-code these arrays.

For example, I have:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
```

How can I get my program to print out what all the integers are in a program?

I want to be able to find the integers in the program that are incremented by one. (allints)++?

Comment: are they really ints? because if they are instances of a class (eg Platform) it's easy to do. Built in types, not so much.

Comment: @KateGregory No, they aren't ints... They are instances of a struct/class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one needs to iterate over a bunch of objects of the same type the typical data structure one uses is an array (old school) or a collection of some kind, depending on secondary requirements like uniqueness, sortedness etc. (new school). This would work with arrays of built-in types as well as with arrays of structs.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @haywire What makes you think I have a new question? Because I was asking whether I am  missing something? I meant: Did I miss something in the OP's question. Because the answer seemed obvious: If you need to know all your objects and want to iterate over them later, put them in a container. But perhaps the OP didn't explain his problem sufficiently, or I was, well, missing something he did explain. (Btw, I just read the OP's comment to the other post with the "ctor puts the class in vector". That seems a good approach (with pointers), and I think I understand better what the OP wanted.)

Comment: questions should be asked in comments. no offense

Answer (score 2):

At some stage, you'll need to hardcode it.
You can create a class that contains your ints and make a function to autoincrement all by one.

Something like:

```
class allints {
    int a, b, c, d;
    public:
        void autoincrement() {
            ++a, ++b, ++c, ++d;
        }
}
```

Or simply a vector of ints and loop it to autoincrement, as following:

```
allints = vector<int> (4, 0); //size 4, at the start value of 0.

void autoincrement(vector<int> v) {
    for(int i: v) ++i;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Noticing that you would be using structs or Classes, just group them in a vector and iterate them (like my 2nd example above)

Comment: I was thinking in making them classes, and making sure the constructor would put the class itself inside a vector... That would work very well.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the class constructor I do `vectorofPlatforms.pushback(this);`

I have posted my own answer as none of you had thought of this approach, but I've giving you upvotes for your nice answers.